# Convert PDF to JPG with ImageMagick: wrong content with weird characters

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, ghostscript, imagemagick-convert

When converting some PDF files to JPG with GhostScript or ImageMagick, the content of each is not good. There are weird characters and unknown text like this:

JPG result:

```
%PDF-1.7
%???
1 0 obj
<</Type/Catalog/Pages 2 0 R/Lang(fr-FR) /MetaData 15 0 R/ViewerPreferences 16 0 R>>
endobj
2 0 obj
```

ImageMagick command:

```
convert -density 300 -background white -alpha remove -limit memory 1 -limit map 1 -quality 100 $pdf_path_long $jpg_path
```

This problem only happens on my production server (locally, the JPG files are created normally). And only for some PDF files but I do not know which ones.
For example, one that does not work is a Word file (.docx) saved in PDF from a Apple Mac.

Is it a encoding problem? Why does it happen only on the production server and not locally? What can I do for fix it on server?

Comment: As per the bug report you opened in the Ghostscript Bugzilla tracker (https://bugs.ghostscript.com/show_bug.cgi?id=700471), there is insufficient information to answer your question. You have not supplied an example input file or output, the text you quoted is simply the header of a PDF file. I refer interested parties to the thread in the bug tracker.

Comment: Do you have different versions of ImageMagick and their delegates, especially libjpeg and Ghostscript on your two systems? I would check that first and be sure they are identical. Also check that you have the same Ghostscript fonts.